# ViewData is not passed to layout in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

**Edited**

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 website which I've scaffolded all of its Identity items. The scaffolding process created a layout file in this location:

`/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml`

As I wanted to use the layout globally, I have moved the layout file (with cut-paste) to this new location:

`/Views/Shared/AdminLayout/_Layout.cshtml`

Then created a `_ViewStart.cshtml` file in the first location to use the layout in the 2nd location. The content of `_ViewStart` file is this:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/AdminLayout/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["ThisOneWorks"] = "some value";
}
```

Now the problem is, `ViewData`s that I set from scaffolded pages (e.g. `SetPassword.cshtml`, `ExtenalLogins.cshtml`, ...) are not working in the layout file. For example `ViewData["Title"]` is always empty, but the `ViewData` that I've set in the `_ViewStart` is working.

The question is, How can I use `ViewData` from scaffolded identity files when I'm using a layout from the shared view folder?

**Edit 1:**

It seems the problem is with this line:

```
ViewData["ThisOneWorks"] = "some value";
```

When I remove it from the `_ViewStart`, all other `ViewData`s work correctly, but why?

Comment: Is the code in a public repo?

Comment: Have you tried with an index string without exclamation mark (!) e.g. ViewData["Title"]

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes, that is only a sample in the SO question. I use another index string in the code and it only has English chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well , it take me quite a lot of time to reproduce the same issue and debug . And finally , I find out it's a known bug .

1. In which case will the bug occur ?

If you try to render a page that has an associated `_ViewStart.cshtml` , and if you set the `ViewData` within the `ViewStart` at the same time , the `_Layout.cshtml` will not render its `ViewData` correctly .

2. The reason why it cannot work .

In short , the reason is that the `ViewData` within the `Layout` is the `ViewContext.ViewData` , instead of the `this.ViewData` that you set in your page .  See [the detailed explanation here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7675#issue-315275585)

3. Walkaround

The bug has been fixed in `2.2.0-preview1`, and unfortunately there's no plan to fix it in `2.1.x`. If you don't want to update your sdk ,  you can use the `HttpContext.Items` . Set `Items` in your RazorPage :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";                   // not working
    HttpContext.Items["Title"]="Workaround - Title"; // workaround
}
```

render `Items` in your `_Layout`:

```
<h1>@Context.Items["Title"]----render in layout</h1>
```

Comment: Here it seems to work with *ViewContext.ViewData[]*, not ViewData or HttpContext.ViewData.Items

Answer (score 0):

Please use the ViewData Attribute if you want to pass it to the Layout

```
[ViewData]
public string Title {get; set;}
```